# Finding out what number occurance of a matching pattern is under your cursor?

Tags: regular-expression

I know that if you press `n` you can hop to the next occurrence of a matching pattern, and that if you want to go to the previous match, you press `N`.

But if my cursor is already in the middle of a match, how do I tell what number match that is from the top of the document?

Comment: The answers to [this StackOverflow question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23975604/in-vim-how-do-i-get-the-total-number-of-matches-after-doing-a-search) tend to show the number of the current match as well as the total number of matches.  [My solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23975604#comment-36954682) displays `(3/5)` in the statusbar, although it counts matching lines, not matches.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `n` flag with the substitution command.

```
:%s/set//gn
```

Or use the current search pattern via `:%s///gn`.

You can also use `:vimgrep` and the quickfix list. Search for your pattern via:

```
:vimgrep/set/ %
```

This searches the current file, `%`, and adds the matches to the quickfix list. Then you can move through the quickfix list via `:cnext` or `:cprevious`. Upon moving through the quickfix list text will display at the bottom showing something like this `(4 of 10)`. By using the `:copen` command a window showing the quickfix results will open. Move to the pattern via pressing `<cr>` on a quickfix item.

However I prefer to use a plugin for this. [vim-indexed-search](https://github.com/henrik/vim-indexed-search) gives you a message in the command line such as:

```
2 of 32 matches
```

This will tell what number match that is from the top of the document.

Comment: There's a caveat with `:vimgrep/set/ %`, that you have to already have the file saved, but it works great! Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You can do this with one command :

```
:1,.s/<C-r><C-w>//gn
```

Decomposing :

```
:1,.s/      " start a substitute command from top of the document to current line
<C-r><C-w>  " paste the content of the word under the cursor
//          " replace with noting
gn          " don't actually replace
```

And in normal mode you can create a mapping for better use :

```
nnoremap <leader>n :1,.s/<C-r><C-w>//gn<CR>
```

See `:h c_<C-R>_<C-W>` for further references.

**Edit**
If you want to rely on your previously entered search pattern, you can replace `<C-R><C-W>` by `<C-R>/`. As the `/` register is the search register, it contains the last search pattern.

Answer (score 2):

This should just be a comment but as I don't have the reputation to comment here goes.

This won't be accurate for multi occurrences on the one line but

```
First
yiw
Then
:1,.s/<C-R>"//gn
```

To discombobulate

```
`yiw` will select the yank the word under the cursor  to register `"` .

`:1,.` does something from line 1 to the current line in command mode 

`<C-R>"` means Ctrl-r" which pastes the contents of register " to the command line

`s/<C-R>"//gn` searches for the value in `"` or `yes` and replaces nothing but counts matches.
```

eg for the following with the cursor on a `yes` in line 5 the above will say 10 matches on 5 lines

```
1    yes no yes
2    yes no yes
3    yes no yes
4    yes no yes
5    yes no yes
6    yes no yes
7    yes no yes
```

Comment: `viwy` -> `yiw` (visual detour unnecessary)

Comment: Yeah my bad what I was doing wasn't working so I did it the roundabout way . I'll update

Comment: You don't even need to `yiw`. You can instead put `<cword>` in the substitute command and it will be replaced with the current word under the cursor on execution. `:help <cword>` for more details and other such keywords.

Comment: <cword> was something I learned form this thread and bery useful it was to :)